# Avoid escape sequence and split the string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a requirement to split the below string and get the values. Have tried with the **JS string split method** but it is not working for backslash split(). Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
Input string = "11,22;0:0/0\0}0#0&"

Output:
, => 11,
; => 22
: => 0
/ => 0
\ => 0
} => 0
# => 0
& => 0
```

Comment: please provide the code you have tried. We can look into it and help you.

Comment: `split` produces an array, not a mapping. Did you plan to post-process the output?

Comment: Yeah, I will take care of convering array to map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a modification with reference to a lot of reading. Hope you find this useful. The '0' with an escape character is also printed in this solution. Please check it.

```js
let string = "26,67;4:79/9\0}0&";

    string = encodeURI(string);
    string = string.replace("%0", "&");
    string = decodeURI(string);
    numbers = string.split(/,|;|:|\/|\\|}|&/);
    finalList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] != "")
            finalList.push(parseInt(numbers[i]));
    }
    console.log(finalList);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me. Please try the below code.

```
let string = "26,67;4:79/9\0}0&";
let arr = string.split(/,|;|:|\/|\\|}|&/);     // ["26", "67", "4", "79", "9 ", "0", ""]
```

Thank you...